# is this binomial distribution correct?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to work out what is the chances of getting the following marks $(100\%, 70\%, 60\%, 50\%)$ in a paper containing $50$ questions, each question containing yes/no options.

Using Binomial Distribution: $$P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

The following results were obtained:

- $100\%$ in assessment: $0.0000000000000888178\%$ chance
- $70\%$ (Grade A in university) in assessment: $0.199913\%$ chance
- $60\%$ (Grade B in university) in assessment: $0.041859\%$ chance
- $50\%$ (Grade C in university) in assessment: $0.112275\%$ chance
- $40\%$ (Grade D in university) in assessment: $0.041859\%$ chance

I have triple-checked and got same results. I want to know if this is definitely correct due to it seems less of a chance getting $40\%$ than getting $50\%$ for example.

Comment: Using P(correct answer)=$1/2$, and assuming that the percentage levels are exact values and not minimum scores, i.e., 50% means scoring exactly 50% and not 50% or greater, the probabilities you calculated look good to me.

Comment: The first two are correct. The last three are the actual probabilities, not the percentages: you forgot to shift the decimal point. E.g., the percentage for a score of exactly $60$% should be $4.1859$%.

Comment: @zach Do you know how I can get it to calculate 50% or grater rather than just 50%? I assumed it was 50% or greater but I was wrong

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for that info, But I am not sure why more chance getting 50% then 40%, even though as Zach said I am kind of not doing it correctly as I want it 50% and greater or 40% and greater, not just getting the exact value

Comment: If $X$ = the event that the test score is 50% or greater, then $P(X)=\sum_{i=25}^{50} {50\choose i} (\frac{1}{2})^{50} $. You can adjust the summation accordingly to find the probabilities for different intervals in the "at least" condition.

Comment: As @zach noted, the number that you’re calculating are the probabilities of getting **exactly** those scores; you’ve more work to do if you want the probabilities of getting **at least** those scores.

Comment: Legends guys, legends, thank you very much both of you :)

Comment: You're assuming the chance of any question being answered correctly is 50/50. Like 50 coin flips. In which case 30heads/20tails has identical probability as 30tails/20heads.

Comment: You would probably want to find the probabilities of being in the range $70$ to $98$ (so excluding $100$), in the range $60$ to $68$, and so on. This involves summing probabilities given by the formula. Many programs (spreadshhets, Alpha) will do it.